# Python - Networkx search predecessor nodes - Maximum depth exceeded

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, networkx

I'm working in a project using the library Networkx ( for graph management ) in Python, and I been having trouble trying to implement what I need

I have a collection of directed graphs, holding special objects as nodes and weights associated with the edges, the thing is I need to go through the graph from output nodes to input nodes. and for each node I have to take the weights from their predecessors and an operation calculated by that predecessor node to build the operation form my output node. But the problem is that the operations of the predecessors may depend from their own predecessors, and so on, so I'm wondering how I can solve this problem.

So far I have try the next, lets say I have a list of my output nodes and I can go through the predecessors using the methods of the Networkx library:

```
# graph is the object containig my directe graph 
for node in outputNodes:
    activate_predecessors(node , graph)

# ...and a function to activate the predecessors .. 
def activate_predecessors( node = None  , graph ):
    ws = [] # a list for the weight
    res = [] # a list for the response from the predecessor
    for pred in graph.predecessors( node ):
        # get the weights 
        ws.append( graph[pred][node]['weight'] )

        activate_predecessors( pred , graph )
        res.append( pred.getResp() )  # append the response from my predecessor node to a list, but this response depend on their own predecessors, so i call this function over the current predecessor in a recursive way 


    # after I have the two lists ( weights and the response the node should calculate a reduce operation

     # do after turning those lists into numpy arrays...
     node.response = np.sum( ws*res )
```

This code seems to work... I tried it on in some random many times, but in many occasions it gives a **maximum recursion depth exceeded**  so I need to rewrite it in a more stable ( and possibly iterative  ) way in order to avoid maximum recursion. but I'm running out of ideas to handle this..

the library has some searching algorithms [(Depth first search)](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/algorithms.traversal.html) but after I don't know how it could help me to solve this.

I also try to put some flags on the nodes to know if it had been already activated but I keep getting the same error.

Edit: I forgot, the input nodes have a defined response value so they don't need to do calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your **code may contain an infinite recursion** if there is a cycle between two nodes. for example:

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,1)])

def activate_nodes(g, node):               
    for pred in g.predecessors(node):
        activate_nodes(g, pred)

activate_nodes(G, 1)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

if you have possible cycles on one of the graphs you better mark each node as visited or change the edges on the graph to have no cycles.

assuming you do not have cycles on your graphs here is an example of how to implement the algorithm iteratively:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3])
G.add_edges_from([(2, 1), (3, 1), (2, 3)])

G.node[1]['weight'] = 1
G.node[2]['weight'] = 2
G.node[3]['weight'] = 3

def activate_node(g, start_node):          
    stack = [start_node]
    ws = []

    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        preds = g.predecessors(node)
        stack += preds
        print('%s -> %s' % (node, preds))
        for pred in preds:
            ws.append(g.node[pred]['weight'])

    print('weights: %r' % ws)
    return sum(ws)


print('total sum %d' % activate_node(G, 1))
```

this code prints:

```
1 -> [2, 3]
3 -> [2]
2 -> []
2 -> []
weights: [2, 3, 2]
total sum 7
```

### Note

you can reverse the direction of the directed graph using [`DiGraph.reverse()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.unary.reverse.html)

if you need to use DFS or something else you can reverse the graph to get the predecessor as just the directly connected neighbours of that node. Using this, algorithms like DFS might be easier to use.

Comment: thanks for your complete answer.  the graphs i'm studying are almost random, but i soon will need to add more control to the way how this sctrucures are created. thanks

Comment: happy to help, please accept the answer if you find it correct :)