# Networkx: How to iterate on ALL edges of a DiGraph, in a breadth-first manner?

Tags: python, networkx, directed-acyclic-graphs, digraphs

I have a networkx DiGraph (not necessarily acyclic). All nodes have a common predecessor : the source node 0.

I want to be able to edit the attributes of all edges, in a breadth first order. To do so, I would like to be able to iterate on ALL edges, starting from source, in a breadth-first manner.

bfs_edges allows classic breadth-first search, which leads to the following issue: if a node has n direct predecessors, only one edge will appear in the iterator, instead of n.

My edges :

```
([(0.0, 1), (1, 2), (1, 7), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 7), (6, 7)])
```

what bfs_edges returns :

```
for edge in nx.bfs_edges(digraph,0):
print(edge[0], edge[1])

0 1
1 2
1 7
2 3
2 4
3 5
3 6
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using NetworkX bfs_predecessors is better for your case, since it returns a iterator of predecessors. You can find the documentation for this method [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_predecessors.html#networkx.algorithms.traversal.breadth_first_search.bfs_predecessors) with this example.

```
>>> G = nx.path_graph(3)
>>> print(dict(nx.bfs_predecessors(G, 0)))
{1: 0, 2: 1}
>>> H = nx.Graph()
>>> H.add_edges_from([(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6)])
>>> dict(nx.bfs_predecessors(H, 0))
{1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 2, 6: 2}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to find all predecessors from a node, you need to iteratively run NetworkX [predecessors](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.DiGraph.predecessors.html) and print the nodes, the following example do that.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from([1,2,3])
G.add_edges_from([(2, 1), (3, 1), (2, 3)])

def activate_node(g, start_node):          
    stack = [start_node]

    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        preds = g.predecessors(node)
        stack += preds
        print('%s -> %s' % (node, preds))

activate_node(G, 1)
```

This will print:

```
1 -> [2, 3]
3 -> [2]
2 -> []
2 -> []
```

The code above was adapted from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799844/python-networkx-search-predecessor-nodes-maximum-depth-exceeded).

Comment: It does work in a breadth first manner, but I'm afraid it does not return an iterator on all edges...

Comment: Edited, see if this helps you.